# Unable to use Azure IOThub client lib in Raspberry PI

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-iot-hub

I am following [Raspberry Pi with Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-raspberry-pi-kit-python-get-started) but i am getting errors when trying to execute "app.py".

I first run command as follows:

```
  sudo chmod u+x setup.sh
  sudo ./setup.sh
```

Next

```
 python app.py 'HostName=xxxx.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=device1;SharedAccessKey=GMMxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxB5o='
```

so it should use by default python. but got an error as follows
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "app.py", line 10, in <module>
 from iothub_client import IoTHubClient, IoTHubClientError, 
IoTHubTransportProvider, IoTHubClientResult
ImportError: No module named iothub_client
```

Next, I tired everything as follows:

```
sudo ./setup.sh -p 3.5
python3.5 app.py 'HostName=xxxx.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=device1;SharedAccessKey=GMMxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxB5o='
```

so it should use  python 3.5. but got same error as above

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 10, in <module>
from iothub_client import IoTHubClient, IoTHubClientError, 
IoTHubTransportProvider, IoTHubClientResult
ImportError: No module named iothub_client
```

It's same error again.

Update: here is a snip from RPI

[image]

Comment: Make sure you build successfully. After that, you will find iothub_client.so in this folder: "iot-hub-python-raspberrypi-client-app".

Comment: It has build successfully, i am attaching a snip in my question. as i checked. i did not get "iothub_client" but it has azure-iot-sdk-python.

Comment: although i cloned this project in new local dir and it worked like a champ.